# R shiny - problemas na publicação

Tags: r, shiny

Boa tarde, estou com dificuldade em publicar um sistema de lógica difusa com o R Shiny.
O sistema roda normalmente no ambiente R, mas ao publicar o sistema me retorna a mensagem de erro: 
The application failed to start (exited with code 1).
Error in value[3L] : não é possível mudar o diretório de trabalho
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> 
Execução interrompida

```
sets_options("universe",seq(1,100,1))
variaveis <- set(
Grupo_familiar = fuzzy_partition(varnames = c( gemin  = 5, gemen = 15, gemed = 50, gemaior=75, gemax=90), sd = 10),
```

Esse mesmo código se repete para todas variáveis.
Então eu passo a definir as regras

```
regras <- set(fuzzy_rule( Grupo_familiar %is%   gemaior && Impacto_economico %is%   rimen   && Trabalho_infantil %is%   ecmaior && Saude %is%   plmin   && Seguranca %is%   gsmax   && Impacto_ambiental %is%   hcmed   , Classificacao %is%    altissima   ),
```

A mesma regra se aplica a todo sistema. Depois disso eu defino as Fluid Row (todas funcionam)
Eu acredito que os problemas estejam nos input/output

```
server <- function(input, output) {
 output$GrafSistema<-renderPlot({plot(sistema)})
observeEvent(input$Processar,{
 inferencia <- fuzzy_inference(sistema,list(Grupo_familiar=input$sgf,Impacto_economico=input$sie,Trabalho_infantil=input$sti,Saude=input$sis,Seguranca=input$sisg,
                                           Impacto_ambiental=input$sia))
output$Grafresultado<-renderPlot({
  plot(sistema$variables$Classificacao)
  lines(inferencia,col='red',lwd=5)})
 })}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: por favor coloque o resto do código do app para que o e exemplo possa ser reproduzido.

Comment: Eu havia esquecido da postagem depois de conseguir solucionar o problema, só não sei como que eu coloco o script correto agora.